# if-else statements are toggling on every pixel i scroll

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scrolltop

I want to make a simple effect where when i scroll till the navigation appears on top, the navigation becomes fixed and thus stays there, but when in scroll to top again, the nav again become non-fixed. I used this script i found somewhere, but after the nav touched the top of screen, it keps toggling between the fixed and static positions, that is, the if and else statements. The jquery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $("nav").offset().top;
    var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollY > y) {
        var padY = scrollY - y;
        $("nav").css({'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'width': '100%'}).stop(); 

    }
      else{

      $("nav").css({'position': 'static', 'width': '100%'}).stop(); 
      }

});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QB3tV/7/

Answer (score 0):

`(scrollY > y)` will change with every scrolled pixel, because you are changing the position after measuring it. Try `(scrollY >= y)` or add a 'ghost' element that doesn't get the `fixed` style added, and make the decision based on that.

For example, based on your jsfiddle:

Add the ghost element:

```
<div id="ghost"></div>
<nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <ul> . . .
```

Then change the measured element:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var y = $("#ghost").offset().top;
    var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    . . .
```

Then it should work perfectly.

http://jsfiddle.net/xRBq5/

There is a `position:sticky` attribute proposed (see [here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit)) but support is currently [very poor](http://caniuse.com/css-sticky).

Comment: is there a method except the  scrollY > y? as this is calculating on every scroll

Comment: Updated the answer with an example

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct. Glad to have helped :-)